# Office Add-in Internet Explorer cannot find path

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, excel-addins, office-js

I am getting started with Office Add-ins through the Java script API. I am going through [this](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/build-your-first-excel-add-in) tutorial. When I proceed with the Try It Out section. I get [this](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/24060/20160729-c85l-35kb.jpg) error. I am getting the add-in to run fine when I give the absolute path in the source location node of the manifest for example `E:\Excel-Add-in-Javascript\first-excel-addin\Home.html` but its the relative path that is not working for example `\\SAAD\Excel-Add-in-Javascript\first-excel-addin\Home.html` Kindly let me know if you a solution.

Comment: After which of the 12 steps do you encounter this error? Also, what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The source location node should not contain a relative path. It should use a complete path, either on the internet or on a network share.

In your case, you need to make \\SAAD a network share, not just a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that serving from the file path (`file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/something.html`) or share is a supported scenario.  It *may* work, but note that it will run differently (and sometimes not run, or be overly permissive) than when you deploy the app for real.

To be clear, you *can* have a **manifest file** on a network share for ease of testing the add-in -- and in fact, it's the easiest way to get your add-in registered with Office desktop.  But the **web content** should be served off of a web server (anything from hosting via an IIS local-host web server, to using an Azure Website, to putting your content on github and serving it via https://rawgit.com/).